# Send message to all connected clients socket.io

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I am using below code to send the message to a particular client sessionId.

> this.sockets[sessionId].json().send(message)

But i don't know, How to send message to all connected clients(browser) instead of sending to one.

Answer (score 4):

Look into this Cheatsheet

sending to sender-client only

```
socket.emit('message', "this is a test");
```

sending to all clients, include sender

```
io.emit('message', "this is a test");
```

sending to all clients except sender

```
socket.broadcast.emit('message', "this is a test");
```

sending to all clients in 'game' room(channel) except sender

```
socket.broadcast.to('game').emit('message', 'nice game');
```

sending to all clients in 'game' room(channel), include sender

```
io.in('game').emit('message', 'cool game');
```

sending to sender client, only if they are in 'game' room(channel)

```
socket.to('game').emit('message', 'enjoy the game');
```

sending to all clients in namespace 'myNamespace', include sender

```
io.of('myNamespace').emit('message', 'gg');
```

sending to individual socketid

```
socket.broadcast.to(socketid).emit('message', 'for your eyes only');
```